# Why -b option disables settings.gradle?

Tags: gradle, multi-module

[11.5. Selecting which build to execute](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:selecting_build) states that:

> When you run the gradle command, it looks for a build file in the
>   current directory. You can use the -b option to select another build
>   file. If you use -b option then settings.gradle file is not used.

I have multi-module project whose `settings.gradle` includes submodules.

How can I workaround this?

Comment: Isn't `-c` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Opal That's it, mate! Thank you! You should answer the question so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `-c` what you're looking for? With `-c` you can pass a `settings.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering for further.

Actually, when I shoud use `-b` option, `-c` option doesn't work at all.

```
$ gradle -b _build.gradle -c settings.gradle
```

Document says

> Alternatively, you can use the -p option to specify the project
>   directory to use. For multi-project builds you should use -p option
>   instead of -b option.

I have to make a directory and use `-p` option.

```
$ ls -F
gradlep/    sub1/    sub2/
$ ls gradlep
build.gradle settings.xml
```

Though, I can invoke gradle in root directory

```
$ gradle -p gradlep build
```